# Pri Slave Drive - ATAPI Incompatible

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, compact-disc, windows-98

I’m attempting to restore an old Windows 98 PC from 2002. The CMOS battery was obviously dead so I replaced it. Everything works, except for the CD ROM drive. Every time I boot the computer, I get the error:

Pri Slave Drive - ATAPI Incompatible

Press F1 to Resume

If I press F1 and continue to Windows 98, the drive does not show up. However, there is an interesting A drive titled "Removable Disk (A:). I don't have any drives in the computer other than the hard drive and CD ROM, so that is strange to me and perhaps is related.

In the BIOS (AMIBIOS Release 09/12/2002 S), all drives are set to be auto detected. However, if I press enter on the second drive (AKA what should be the CD ROM) which is supposed to detect the type of drive, it sets the type of drive to ARMD (ATAPI Removable Media Device). This is similar to what Windows detects. I have already attempted to set the BIOS to its defaults.

As for physical jumpers, the drive is on the same cable as the hard drive and the jumper is set to slave. This should work as it was what was in the computer originally. I would assume that the drive worked at some point as there was a disk in it when I got the computer.

How can I get the CD ROM drive to be detected by the BIOS and Windows? Do I have a hardware fault?

Comment: try Cable Select on both drive jumpers, some motherboards do not play well with master slave configurations.

Comment: Could you briefly explain what the cable select jumper does? Do I jumper it alongside the master/slave jumpers, or should it be the only set of pins jumpered?

Comment: CS allows the motherboard (drive controller) to decide master slave configuration, not the drive itself. Only use one jumper at a time, try CS, it should fix the issue.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue. I wonder why the jumpers were set as they were if it didn't work. The drives are also in the wrong order now (CDROM set as master, HDD as slave) but that doesn't seem to affect anything adversely.

Comment: I have only seen this issue on Dell, HP etc PC's, not home built, evidently PC manufacturers decided to use CS. Glad its solved, there is no difference between master and slave and the operation of the device.

Comment: Interesting. This is just a generic PC that a friend of mine had. One of those blank cases with a company badge on the front. Probably not home built, but not made by a manufacturer like Dell or HP. It must be the motherboard.

Comment: The A: drive shows up because the operating system can't really detect whether or not there is a floppy, it simply shows what the BIOS says is there.  You'd have to disable the floppy from the BIOS to remove the A: drive.

Comment: I see. I had already listed the floppy as “Not Installed” in the BIOS, but maybe there’s something else I have to do. Whatever it is, it’s not a big problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moab, in a comment, suggested that a fix could be setting the jumpers on the CDROM and HDD to "cable select" as the motherboard may not work with the master-slave configuration. This fixed the problem, although the CDROM is now master and the HDD is slave. However, this doesn't seem to be causing any problems. The computer boots without the incompatibility error.